# TYPO3 Cookie Law Accept

Tags: cookies, typo3

I use TYPO3 7.6.10
I want to use cookie_consent to have a bar with two buttons "accept", "no accept".
If user not accept i want to disable some scripts.

I tried to add in root template as described in documentation:

```
page {
    10 < plugin.tx_cookieconsent
}
```

but i don't see any bar, where i'm wrong?

There is an other good plugin for typo3 to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I would go with https://silktide.com/tools/cookie-consent/download/, no need for an extension

Comment: I need a decline button. I decided to use a jquery plugin to manage the user choice.

Comment: Another script-only solution which allows to decline cookies, too: https://cookieconsent.insites.com/